# No error output for ruby commands

Tags: bash, zsh, ruby

I am currently having the following problem:

Some of my ruby/rbenv commands commands (e.g.: `bundle exec irb`, `rbenv rehash`) fail when executing.

However I don't get any error output:

```
[~]$ bundle exec irb                                                                                                
[~]$ echo $?                                                                                                         
1
```

I use zsh (via oh-my-zsh) but switching to bash didn't solve the problem.

Is there a way to see the error output from the last command?

Comment: This looks like you have `STDERR` redirected somewhere other than the terminal.

Comment: This might be the case. How can see where STDERR is redirected?

Comment: I am unsure what else is in your environment, but whatever it is, it may be changing the value of `$stderr` to a file or a log.  Open up IRB and check the value of `$stderr` to get a hint of where it may be redirected to.